# Additional ground area for thermal mass

Tags: pcb, ground-plane

My 2-layer PCB has a ground plane on the bottom layer and almost everything is routed on the front layer.

I'm using a [MCP1501 Voltage Reference](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MSLD/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MCP1501-Data-Sheet-DS20005474F.pdf), its data sheet says:

> Of particular importance is the grounding of the device to a large
> ground plane with good thermal mass. The MCP1501 should not be placed
> on a small daughter card or connected to ground via long traces or
> single vias if Load Coefficient is to be optimized [...]

The load should be less than 1mA but still I thought it might be a good idea to add a ground area on the front layer to provide the MCP1501 with some thermal mass, because it actually is connected to ground plane only via some vias.

Blue is the ground plane and red is the "thermal mass" ground area:

[image: PCB with ground plane plus ground area]

- U1: [MCP1501](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MSLD/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MCP1501-Data-Sheet-DS20005474F.pdf)
- U2: ATMega328P
- U3: [TMP36](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/TMP35_36_37.pdf)
- U4: [HIH-5030](https://prod-edam.honeywell.com/content/dam/honeywell-edam/sps/siot/en-us/products/sensors/humidity-with-temperature-sensors/hih-5030-5031-series/documents/sps-siot-hih5030-5031-series-product-sheet-009050-2-en-ciid-49692.pdf?download=false)

I've added two vias to connect that ground area with ground plane.

I am unsure if this ground area is a good idea. It is broken which is maybe not good at all.

The experimental circuit on a breadboard works well. The project is here: [Thermidity](https://github.com/gitdode/thermidity)

**Update**: I followed Tim William's recommendation on measuring ratiometrically and replaced the temperature sensor with a thermistor. So there is no need for a voltage reference with all these advantages:

- fewer parts
- simpler circuit and PCB
- better accuracy (0.1°C thermistor + 0.1% series resistance) vs. ±1-2°C temperature sensor)
- lower power consumption

Comment: Which are the ICs? What is it doing? If U1 or U3 is the reference and U2 is an MCU, and U4 is a... humidity sensor, perhaps?, then does it really need any accuracy at all -- would a ratiometric measurement not suffice?

Comment: I don't think **thermal** mass is the right term. It would be the right term if you needed to soak a lot of heat joules up in a short space of time but, I doubt that is the case here.

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams, improved my answer and yes, it is a humidity sensor and some calculation has to be done. The MCU seems overkill but it also has font bitmaps stored on it and drives an E-Ink display to display temperature, humidity (and battery voltage).

Comment: @Andyaka, so that additional ground area is not necessary and maybe does more harm than good?

Comment: Would you be satisfied with a thermistor (resistor divider with one dependent on temperature) instead of the TMP36? Then maybe you can eliminate the VREF and use ratiometric measurements only (assuming you aren't reading analog inputs on the header(s)). Note that ATMega328 is only 10-bit ADC, which you're lucky to get even that, so a reference as accurate as MCP1501 isn't doing much for you.

Comment: @TimWilliams Followed your advice (see update). Very satisfied with the result, measurements are very stable and accurate. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't matter:

1. Your required accuracy is low. Namely: the MCP1501 is 0.1%, while the ATMega328P ADC is 10-bit, from which you're lucky to get ~8 bits (absolute accuracy) out of it.
2. Your ref consumption is small (under 1mA?), so its heating will be small.
3. At least for the humidity sensor, its reading is ratiometric (page 2, general notes), so is independent of the ref, as long as it's not exceptionally noisy at ADC-sample-time frequencies, and above the minimum required Vref.

The purpose of their recommendation is this:

Because the reference is designed for a very tight output, every little influence matters.  That is, the output can vary by fractional millivolts with device temperature, supply voltage, load current, even device stress (not usually specified, but if you have a voltmeter with even more digits of accuracy, you might see it vary when pressing on the device, or flexing the board).

This is after accounting for foreseeable influences -- notice the block diagram indicates temperature compensation already.  There are additional sources of error, which cannot be compensated out (manufacturing variation), thus leaving some bounded error with respect to these parameters.

So, keeping the temperature low, and more stable (more thermal mass), helps reduce drift, and low-frequency or flicker noise.

Unless you're drawing a lot of current (10s mA?), the lower thermal resistance of the pour probably doesn't matter.  The thermal mass has essentially no effect because the base accuracy outperforms your ADC.

Note that several vias should be used, to get a good (thermal and electrical) connection between top and bottom pours.  @ronsimpson's answer addresses this:

[image: Layout with added thermal vias]

Additional vias should be used around the pour, to "stitch" them together, particularly around traces, rows of pads, etc. which act to cut up either pour.  This reduces stray ground inductance and resistance, improving high-frequency performance.

General design tips:

I would recommend using one of the higher grade TL431 variants with the ATMega328P: the accuracy is slightly poorer (0.5% versions are available), cost is lower, and the size is smaller.  That is, if you need a reference at all.  Again, temperature is easy to measure ratiometrically, say using a thermistor (<1% types are available), and the humidity sensor is ratiometric.

To be clear about the importance of "ratiometric": an ADC is NOT a voltage measuring device.  It is a multilevel comparator, which compares an input relative to a reference voltage.  The ADC intrinsically reads a voltage ratio.  A preferred interpretation of the ADC result (the digital value) is as a fixed-point (all fractional) number, describing how much (0-100%) of the reference was sensed on a given sample -- a unitless value.  If you know your reference voltage at the instant of sampling, then you also know the input voltage, but maybe the reference itself varies some over time, between devices, or other influences.  But if you're measuring a different variable anyway, it might not matter.  The simplest example is a potentiometer, whose voltage is a strict ratio of the supply.  If that supply equals the ADC reference, then the pot setting is a ratio, and the ADC reading is a ratio -- completely independent of Vref (as long as Vref is sufficient for the ADC to do its job).

In this case, temperature and humidity can be acquired directly as ratios, eliminating their dependency on a voltage reference.

If you intend to measure other signals with this board, consider providing Vref on a pin so that attached devices can supply ratiometric signals when possible.

If fully ratiometric readings are not possible in the overall system, then a voltage reference is acceptable.  You can use a fairly cheap device (like TL431 as mentioned), or use a very accurate one (like MCP1501, LM4041, etc.) to shift the dominant error to the ADC itself and eliminate any need to calibrate the reference / readings.

You haven't mentioned any extenuating constraints (such as cost, size, ability to calibrate, etc.), so I cannot suggest one of these options for you.  I can only interpret what you've designed (MCP1501 seems to suggest the latter i.e. making the ADC the dominant source of error), and give the tradeoffs for other possible designs.

On the matter of high-frequency performance, and EMC in general: you might consider an input filter around J1, as it current provides a direct route for high-frequency interference (RFI) to flow into the reference, which may disturb it (rectification effects).  Likewise, the headers may benefit from filtering and ESD protection; exposing naked MCU pins on headers is generally poor practice.  (But it depends on what this is doing.  If it's just a small riser board to a larger system that does provide such protection, for example, that's fine.)

Comment: Thank you for this great and instructive answer. As you have certainly guessed I am not a pro (more like a beginner) and didn't know about ratiometric measurement. The device is battery powered meaning the exact voltage is not known so probably no way around a voltage reference? I added a link to the spare time project with info for what it is supposed to do and what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Ah, just a standalone sensor and display then? Yeah, then everything can be ratios, nice!  Current can be significantly reduced by switching off ref and sensors when not in use -- consider adding a +V switch (e.g. BSS84?) to them.

Comment: ...and finally I understand how ratiometric measurement works. I already have those TMP36's and MCP1501's but will give it a try with a thermistor as you suggested anyway. This could save 140uA for the Vref.
I could also switch the sensors with an MCU pin right? The ATmega can switch 40mA.

Comment: Sure, those could be powered by a GPIO.  Very little load.  Mind, if you're going to put on a supply bypass capacitor for them, do add some series resistance to the pin to limit its peak charging current (say, 47 ohms minimum).

Comment: Et voilà, 43uA instead of 400uA idle current now.

Answer (score 2):

I like large amounts of ground copper.  I do not like running a reference hot. If the reference is running worm adding VIAs will carry heat to the other side of the board.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the effort of making a drawing!